# deploying error in webpart solution sp2013

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, deployment

I developed a webpart to show customer information from a wcf service in sharepoint. 
my webpart was ok, worked fine until I made some settings in project like xml-comments and code analysis. now I can't deploy it, error message: error in deploying: "activate functions" feature "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx" is site-scoped and cannot be added to the web". 
anyone knows, where this error comes from and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What is the scope of the feature and where are you trying to activate it?

I had this issue once, when I deployed a solution with the feature as a web scoped, then later changed to Site Scoped and tried deploying.
The issue was caused due to Multiple entries in the Content Db one for being activated on the Web and another one for Site.

How can we resolve the issue?
Make sure that the current instances of the feature wiht old scope are deactivated before changing the scope and deploying it again using VS.

All I had to do was change the scope of the feature - deploy the solution - deactivate all the instances of the feature - retract the solution completely. Then change the feature scope to the required mode and redeploy.